# Rails3 - wicked_pdf gem, footer issue when calling from action mailer model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

I'm using wicked_pdf pdf_from_string inside an action mailer rails 3 model.
The pdf render perfectly doing this:

attachments["pdf.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(:pdf => "pdf.pdf",:template => 'documents/show.pdf.erb')
   )

When I try to pass the option :footer, it does not work with these options:

```
attachments["pdf.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(:pdf => "pdf.pdf", :template => 'pdf/pdf.html.erb', :layout => 'pdfs/pdf', 
    :footer => {:html => {:template => 'pdf/pdf_footer.html.erb', :layout => 'pdfs/pdf'}, :spacing => -65})
  )
```

Note that :footer option works sweet inside a controller, coming from a controller default 'render' :pdf method.

I ended up doing something like this, but I'd prefer not using gotchas.

```
File.open("/tmp/wicked_pdf_#{@model.number}.html", 'w+b', 0644) { |f|
 f.write render_to_string({:template => 'pdf/pdf_footer.html.erb', :layout => 'pdfs/pdf'})
}
attachments["pdf.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      render_to_string(:pdf => "pdf.pdf", :template => 'pdf/pdf.html.erb', :layout => 'pdfs/pdf'),
      :footer => {:html => {:url => "file:///tmp/wicked_pdf_#{@model.number}.html"}, :spacing => -65}                 
    )
```

Any clue to have this working properly?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be related to the problem in this question:

[Rails 3 ActionMailer and Wicked_PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421615/rails-3-actionmailer-and-wicked-pdf)

Where the mailer doesn't like it when you call render.

Try wrapping your attachment setting in a respond_to block like so:

```
mail(:subject => 'Your pdf', :to => user.email) do |format|
  format.text
  format.pdf do
    attachments['pdf.pdf'] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      render_to_string(
        :pdf      => "pdf.pdf",
        :template => 'pdf/pdf.html.erb',
        :layout   => 'pdfs/pdf', 
        :footer   => {
          :html => {
            :template => 'pdf/pdf_footer.html.erb',
            :layout   => 'pdfs/pdf'
          },
          :spacing => -65
        }                 
      )
  end
end
```

Comment: I need to render an html email with a pdf attached. I tried to do:
    format.html do
        attachments["pdf_#{@model.number}.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
            render_to_string(:pdf => "pdf_#{@model.number}.pdf", :template => 'pdfs/pdf.html.erb', :layout => 'pdfs/pdf', 
                             :footer => {:html => {:template => 'pdf/pdf_footer.html.erb', :layout => 'pdfs/pdf'}, :spacing => -65})
          )
        render :the_html

the pdf is attached, but still don't have footer

Comment: also if use the pdf format the pdf is rendered totally non-styled. footer still missing. is there another solution?

Comment: looking at the code of pdf_helper of the gem 
def make_pdf(options = {})
      html_string = render_to_string(:template => options[:template], :layout => options[:layout])
      options = prerender_header_and_footer(options)
      w = WickedPdf.new(options[:wkhtmltopdf])
      w.pdf_from_string(html_string, options)
    end

I open an issue

Comment: forked the gem with a fix for this; waiting for the pull request to be considered. in the meantime I'm using my fork available here: https://github.com/clod81/wicked_pdf

Comment: calling my fix like this:
attachments["XXX.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string(:pdf => "XXX.pdf", :template => 'pdf.html.erb', :layout => 'pdfs/pdf'), 
        :footer => {:content => render_to_string({:template => 'pdf_footer.html.erb', :layout => 'pdfs/pdf'}), :spacing => -70}
              )